Laravel 11 , Handling Exception in custom Class or Exception for API's
Generally, We handle the exception in
like below in ~/bootstrap/app.php
->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
    $exceptions->respond(function (Response $response, $e, Request $request) {
        if ($e instanceof ValidationException) {
            return response()->json($e->errors(), Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
        } elseif ($e instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
            $result['errorMsg'] = 'Method not allowed.';
            $result['body'] = ['requestedUrl' => $request->getUri()];

            return response()->json($result, Response::HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
        } elseif ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException || $e instanceof NotFoundHttpException  || $e instanceof RouteNotFoundException) {
            $result['errorMsg'] = $e->getMessage() ?? 'Record not found.';
            $result['body'] = ['requestedUrl' => $request->getUri()];

            return response()->json($result, Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        } elseif ($e instanceof AuthenticationException) {
            $result['errorMsg'] = 'Unauthenticated';
            $result['body'] = ['requestedUrl' => $request->getUri()];

            return response()->json($result, Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        } elseif ($e instanceof HttpException) {
            return response()->json($e->getMessage(), $e->getStatusCode());
        } else {
            $result['errorMsg'] = 'Internal server error.';
            $result['body'] = ['requestedUrl' => $request->getUri()];
            $result['exception'] = $e->getMessage();

            return response()->json($result, Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

        return $response;
    });

But,I I want to handle in different way in separate class and Override the ~/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php
public function renderable(callable $renderUsing)
    {

Is there is any way , we can handle ? or customise the reponse?

My advice is this: different people use different ways, from the handler class just the way you are doing, and some from custom class the way you are asking to do. Its almost the same, because even if you create custom classes for each, you may still have to go into each of them and return  their render responses. Just do any one you feel comfortable with.
